# How to restore the official firmware on Samsung Galaxy Note?

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-android, samsung-galaxy-note

I have a question for you guys. When I bought my [Samsung Galaxy Note](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxynote/note/index.html?type=find), it came with custom firmware with lots of bugs. It's being over 3 months I bought this phone and it freezes a lot. My question is, does anyone know how to restore the original firmware from Samsung? Thank you..

```
My Android version   : 2.3.6
Model number         : GT-N7000
Baseband version     : N7000XXLB2
Kernel version       : 2.6.35 14-FM-2.0-g399c932
                       frank_m@VirtualBox
Build number         : GINGERBREAD.XXLC1
Rom version          : KingDroid Elegance Deluxe v7.0
```

Comment: I just found this [tutorial](http://droidangel.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-installflash-samsung-galaxy-note.html) do you guys think, is this what I am looking for? I really don't want to mess up my phone :(

Comment: This question could become the standard "How can I flash stock Android on the Galaxy Note?" question

Comment: I just didn't know it was called stock Android :/ I am new to the whole Anroid concept.

Comment: No problem. That's why everyone can edit your question. :)

Comment: thanks friend! btw, i found another [tutorial](http://techie-buzz.com/android/manually-install-android-4-0-4-ics-xxlrg-update-on-galaxy-note.html) and this looks promising :)

Comment: Be aware that you can answer your own question to gain reputation and help others that are having the same question. If the tutorial works for you, please write the steps as answer down.

Comment: The second tutorial will work well for you.  Just make sure to download the firmware for your particular international model of Note (N7000) and not the T-Mobile (SGH-T879) or AT&T (SGH-I717) versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I expected. Just follow this [tuto](http://techie-buzz.com/android/manually-install-android-4-0-4-ics-xxlrg-update-on-galaxy-note.html) will guide you well.

1. Download Odin
2. Download the related firmware
3. Launch Odin, click on ROM
4. Select the firmware
5. Click on Start button.
6. Pray!

Thank you for everyone who took their time to help me.